# Почему не работает margin:auto 0 у слайдера?

Tags: html, css, slider

Недавно версткой стал заниматься, возникла проблема при вертикальном выравнивании.

В слайдере блок с текстом должен быть по середине вертикально, почему margin:auto 0; не работает? Как видите блок прижат к верху родителя https://parq21.github.io/#testimonials
раздел Testimonials
Как выровнять вертикально? В чем ошибка? Пробовал с помощью :before выровнять, блок вниз почему-то уходит

**Интересует, почему margin не работает.**

Знаю что:

```
top:50%; /*опускаем на 50% высоты род.*/ 
transform: translateY(-50%); /*поднимаем на 50% высоты реб.*/
```

и про flex, таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

и удалите `margin`

Comment: здесь еще есть инфа что марджин вертикально не центрирует https://habrahabr.ru/post/189696/

Answer (score 2):

Используйте ныне популярный Flexbox. Задайте для .slick-slide вот такой набор стилей:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex; 
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

В целом, добавив только `display:flex` все сразу выстраивается в нужный порядок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: рассчитывал без флекса все сделать. С ним все будет работать - это понятно.

Comment: @Batan112 без флекса и без абсолютного позиционирования..как тогда вы хотите? сделайте табличной версткой...

Comment: @Batan112 тогда оберните в еще один тег. Задайте ему `display: table`, вложенному тегу - `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`. Но, я бы использовал Flexbox

Comment: Хорошо, флекс работает. А почему марджин игнорируется, интересно? ведь родитель по высоте больше, высоту фиксированную поставил им.

Comment: @Batan112 конструкция с `margin` будет работать, если у родителя задан `display: flex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0 auto
```

выравнивает блок по горизонтали.

Для того, чтоб выровнять блок по вертикали есть несколько вариантов:

```
position: relative;
```

для родителя, для дочернего элемента:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -0.625em;
```

[Тут подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-center)

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 1.25;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
 width: 30%;
 height: 400px;
  background: black;
  }
  
  .block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: red;
  
  
  }
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "block">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Добавил пример, если знаем высоту элемента, который размещаем по центру. Смещаем на половину его высоты вверх.

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 5em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.625em;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Если нужно размещать текст..

Comment: без абсолютного позиционирования никак? Не хочу прописывать высоту, нужно чтобы блок увеличивался сам в высоту

Comment: вы можете таблично сверстать :) но это не очень хорошая мысль..
а чем вам абсолютное позиционирование не нравится? 
в данном случае элемент будет распологать всегда по центру независимо от размера устройства, на котором просматриваете..

Comment: там текст, абсолютное больше для картинок подойдет. А что если текста много будет, все полетит

Comment: Нет. Ничего не полетит. 
Честно говоря с Вашей стороны не совсем правильно надеяться только на форум и даже не открывать то, что вам присылают.. так как там пример с текстом..Я добавлю сейчас помимо блоков пример с текстом в свой ответ.